# TypeError: this.props.propName.map is not a function react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to fetch JSON data, store it in state and then pass it to component through props. In the component I want to use the `map` function but it shows me this error :
`TypeError: this.props.dataQueries.map is not a function.`
This is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        dataQueries: ''
      }
    }

  fetchData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {method: "GET"}).
    then(res => res.json()).
    then(result => this.setState({ dataQueries: result }));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ShowPosts dataQueries={ this.state.dataQueries } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my component :

```
class ShowPosts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
      this.props.dataQueries.map((query, index) => {
        return index;
      })
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `dataQueries` might be a string, if it came from a request. Parse it before considering it as an array.

Comment: `then(result => this.setState({ dataQueries: JSON.parse(result) }));`

Comment: initialize dataQueries as an array [] instead of empty string ''

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: No, that's part of what `res.json()` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh really, I am not aware of that. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you're setting `dataQueries` to `''`. Which has no `map`, as it's a string.  It's only an array *later*, when your `fetchData` async call has completed. Nothing prevents `render` from being called before the async call completes.

Initialize it to `[]` instead, or modify `render` to avoid trying to use it as an array when it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `this.fetchData()` inside `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. So when component is mounted only then you update the state with response from API. Also, you should render `ShowPosts` component when there are posts to render using conditional rendering.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.dataQueries.length && <ShowPosts dataQueries={ this.state.dataQueries } />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And your initial `dataQueries` should be an empty array. `dataQueries = []`

Comment: `Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.` is mentioned above provided docs link. Calling an external API and setting a callback is kind of a subscription through promise. So `componentWillMount` and `constructor` is recommended when state is being set synchronously which is not the case in this scenario.

Comment: @falloutcoder: I didn't think that's what they meant by subscription (and I'm not sure I still don't), but here's an even stronger statement in support of using `componentDidMount` for ajax: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call Since either way there's going to be an extra render, based on that, I would indeed use `componentDidMount` instead.